Deleting all keyframes causing the rig completely broken
I was animating my rig but if I tried to delete all keyframes my model completely bugged out.
It doesn't matter which keyframes I deleted, but once a bone has no more keyframes they all broke.
After I deleted all keyframes and hit "Clear scale", this is how my model and rig turned out. No clue why this is happening... Any help will be appreciated!
The .blend file



Have you tried also pressing Alt+G and Alt+R to clear the Location and Rotation as well?

I do, and that didn't do anything
I wonder if I accidently did anything when I was animating, but can't recall

I don't have time to check deeply, but try to go to pose mode, select all bones (even hidden layers), set scale to 1,1,1, hold Alt key and press Enter, so to set scale 111 to all bones (some were on 000, causing the issue).

It fixed the issue!!! I suppose it's just that I didn't check every bones but only the controllers... lamo
Still not sure why that happens, but thanks!
